# Python queues - number of task_done()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I wish to know the amount of tasks completed (the sum completed by all threads) for a queue in a multi-threaded program. What is the best way to find this out?
I note that:

1. I've read the documentation and there doesn't appear to be a simple method (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/queue.html).
2. The 'join' method of the queue class suggests that this can be done, as this refers to calling of the task_done() method.
3. The 'qsize' method returns the number of items in the queue that are currently unprocessed (as I understand it) - i.e. does not have a relation to task_done().
4. Solution for python 3.4 is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try extending the Queue class. Something like

```
from queue import Queue

class MyQueue(Queue):

    def __init__(self):
        #In py3, I believe you can just use super()
        #with no args
        super(MyQueue, self).__init__()
        self.completed_count = 0

    def task_done(self):
        self.completed_count += 1
        super(MyQueue, self).task_done()

    def get_task_count(self):
        return self.completed_count
```